# Can I use an op-amp in buffer configuration as a voltage source?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm working on a scale project where I use an INA126 to get my signal. After the filters I need to subtract voltage from it. I'm using an op-amp in the appropriate configuration. It does this operation (signal)—`xvoltage`, where `xvoltage` is the output of the same op-amp in the buffer configuration between a voltage divider, but every time I add weight to the scale the output of the buffer changes.

I don't know how to explain it, since it's not related by any means. Thanks.

By the way, the op-amp I'm using is the LM358.

Comment: It may help us to actually see the opamp drawn out. Any easy way for you to show us what you are talking about is by drawing in this program: http://www.tech-chat.de/aacircuit.html It will convert your circuit to ascii so that you can just copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: When the buffer output changes, does the buffer input change? Answer that, and I bet you'll be closer to solving the problem.

Comment: The two summing nodes shouldn't affect each other.  Can you draw the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

If I read you correctly, you have two op-amps in your circuit. One in a summing configuration, to take your signal and subtract off a constant voltage. The other, call it the reference amp, provides the constant voltage to be subtracted? In principle there's nothing wrong with that. You should be able to present a wide range of load impedances to the reference stage without changing its output voltage.

Actually, op-amps have very high input impedance, so you shouldn't even have to buffer a voltage divider in order to provide the reference voltage to the summing stage. You can add or subtract several signals with a single op-amp, given the correct resistor network.

Just out of curiosity, what are the resistor values you're using?

Comment: Tnxs for ur attention, im using 2k resistors on the lm358 and 1k resistors to gnd to assure cero voltage saturation

this is my schematic: http://www.glowfoto.com/static_image/30-232532L/9652/png/06/2010/img4/glowfoto